# Event receiver on external list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-handlers, external-list

Recently I am working on a project to set event receiver on external list.

Below list what we have done

1. Create trigger to capture data change in database and log them into data table
2. Implement subscribe/unsubscribe function for BDC model
3. Implement subscribe function in SharePoint UI (A separate RESTful endpoint is created for each subscribed event and subscription id is stored in database, we call the endpoint delivery address),**Successful without any error**
4. Implement event receiver and attached it to external list
5. Invoke delivery address through console application. **Successful with "Success" in return XML.**

**Our expectation is when the delivery address is invoked, the event receiver will be fired. But it doesn’t fired.**

We suspect the reason would be

1. The way we bind event receiver

   ```
       string assembly = this.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
   string className = typeof(CustomeTSNBER).FullName;

   try
       {
           using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
           {
               using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
               {
                   SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
                   list.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded,
                      assembly, className);

                   list.Update();
               }
           }
       }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
           throw e;
   }
   ```
2. The way we invoke the delivery address (below is message send to delivery address), and I notice one thing is no matter what I send to delivery address, it return "Success" in returned XML.
   [image]

**Could anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: AFAIK, External lists don't support event receivers - it's one of the limitations

Comment: It's supported in SharePoint 2013 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164024.aspx#FeaturesAddedWithRER

Comment: Not an answer but try breaking it down into components as small as possible to see where it's failing.   Does step 1 occur?  Step 2? Etc...

Comment: Actually I haven't got any error when invoke delivery address, but the event receiver just not fired, don't know why.

Comment: Issue fixed. It turns out we invoke wrong delivery address